# assign a column in a data frame based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe for example

```
 univ  date        ms  kv
  A     11/01/2007  1  0.2
  A     11/02/2007  0  0.3
  A     11/03/2007  1  0.4
  A     11/05/2007  1  0.1
  B     11/01/2007  0  0.11
  B     11/03/2007  1  0.12
  B     11/04/2007  1  0.13
```

For each univ group, I would like to calculate the average of kv, for the next available date after ms = 1. So in the above case for A, ms = 1 on 11/01 and 11/03 and 11/05 so the output should be

```
 univ kv
  A   0.2 ( average of 0.3 and 0.1)
```

I would also like to make the "next available date" flexible that it could be the "the second next or third next available date"

thanks so much!

Comment: Do you have your example correct?  Looks like you want average of `.4` and `.1`

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
In [244]: n=1

In [245]: df.groupby('univ') \
            .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.ms.shift(n)==1, 'kv'].mean()) \
            .reset_index(name='kv')
Out[245]:
  univ    kv
0    A  0.20
1    B  0.13
```

---

```
In [246]: n=2

In [247]: df.groupby('univ') \
            .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.ms.shift(n)==1, 'kv'].mean()) \
            .reset_index(name='kv')
Out[247]:
  univ   kv
0    A  0.4
1    B  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
flexible... change the point at which you start slice `x[n:]`

```
df.query('ms == 1').groupby('univ').kv.apply(lambda x: x[1:].mean())

univ
A    0.25
B    0.13
Name: kv, dtype: float64
```

---

**Option 2**
Not flexible... just messing around with this one

```
df[df.duplicated(['univ', 'ms'])] \
    .query('ms == 1').set_index('univ').kv.mean(level=0)

univ
A    0.25
B    0.13
Name: kv, dtype: float64
```